# WebClient vs WebSocketClient

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I am trying my hands on spring webflux. I am a bit confused on why do we need WebSocketClient, when we have WebClient.

Prior to Spring 5  we had two issues
1. REST call is a blocking call because we were using HttpClient. 
And
2. It was mainly pull mechanism from the client side whenever we need data.

But with Spring 5 and web flux module, we can have something like this on server side

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction () {
        return
                route(
                        GET("/streaming"),  serverRequest -> {

                            Flux<Integer> flow = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).doOnEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.get()));
                            return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON).body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(flow, Integer.class));
                        }
                )
        ;
    }
```

and we can solve two issues mentioned above using WebClient from client side

```
WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080")
        .get()
        .uri("/streaming")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

    IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i -> {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("non blocking");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
```

In this case firstly, the REST call is non blocking which can be validated by the fact that the next statement is executed immediately. And also data is being pushed from  a server side and not pulled from client side.

So if we can do this using WebClient where would I need WebSocketClient.

Comment: To communicate on a websocket, instead of communicating using HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebSocketClient` has two major differences compared to `WebClient`

1. it does not offer a reactive but an async API
2. it operates on a lower abstraction level, reacting on things like connection closed.
3. it uses WebSockets which is bidirectional.

So use cases for the `WebSocketClient` are:

- you want bi-directional communication instead of request/response (with the response possibly being large and arriving piece by piece.
- you want to react to low-level protocol events
- you don't want to depend on Project Reactor

Comment: What about when you need to handle InputStreams as the request or response?